# create custom widget chart for TFS 2015

Tags: tfs, widget, tfs-2015

We have TFS 2015.4 installed on premise:

we need to create custom widgets to be added on dashboards, that will be able to show charts from tree queries(complicated) results and not only flat queries.

is that possible in any way? and what are the limitations when it comes to widgets for dashboard?

Answer (score 1):

The TFS query charts could only be created for flat query. Hierarchical queries are not supported when you using the Charts for workitem Widgets in Dashboard.

Here is an user voice about creating charts for Hierarchical queries. You could vote and add comments here: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/13421301-tfs-widgets-for-query-and-charts-enhancements

To start custom widgets, please refer to this guide:
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/add-dashboard-widget

Comment: is it possible to develop such a widget, where inside its code it connects to SQL and run a stored procedure get some simple results and show them in a chart?

Comment: @JohnnyZghaib you could refer to [this link](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/add-dashboard-widget) to start to custom your widgets. Or submit a uservoice at the site I posted above about your request/

Answer (score 0):

**No it is not possible TFS only supports flat data queries.**

> https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/

You can take a look to the tfs marketplace. If you have a critical TFS installation I would be careful with this extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Pivot Table function.  I can get quit a bit of charting information with a pivot table.

But as it stands, TFS only uses flat data.